# why can't i get the result of a linear programming code using Gurobi?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

This is my first time i use gurobi on python, i want to optimize a simple linear model, when i run this model by calling the function `setc, scan= scan_maker(np.array([[1,1],[2,-1]]),2, 2)` where `setc`and `scan`are two nested functions in the `scan_maker function` it is not giving me any optimization, the only thing that shows me is this following result

```
Changed value of parameter FeasibilityTol to 0.001
   Prev: 1e-06  Min: 1e-09  Max: 0.01  Default: 1e-06
Changed value of parameter OptimalityTol to 0.001
   Prev: 1e-06  Min: 1e-09  Max: 0.01  Default: 1e-06
```

it is a simple model to optimize but it seems that i'm missing something that i couldn't detect, i couldn't post the entire code since it is my first question.

Comment: You probably did not call optimize. Gurobi comes with quite a few examples. You may want to study them.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen i did call optimize by typing ```m.optimize()``` where ```m=Model("scanning")```in my code

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that actually being executed.

Comment: i couldn't post the code because it is my first question on this platform but here is a part of the code where i called the ```optimize()```function: ``` def scan():
        i=1
        init_ =1
        while i>0:
            if i>= init_:
                m.setObjective(x[i],GRB.MAXIMIZE)
                res= m.optimize()
                print(res)
                if m.Status==GRB.OPTIMAL or m.Status==GRB.UNBOUNDED:
                    ub[i]= round(int(x[i]))
                    res=m.optimize()
                    print(res)```